Do Shield-1 cubesat has MLI layer outside the surface?
Did the Shields-1 cubesat have multilayer insulation outside the surface for thermal protection?

While not conclusive as it focuses on the science payloads this presentation appears to show outside as solar panels, and interior structural aluminum.
A source talking specifically about the thermal/structural design would be more authoritative.

thanks @GremlinWranger
